# Configurable level editor

Tags: language-agnostic

I am looking after a level editor easy to use and configurable, so I can use for my own application/engine. Is there something like that?

Comment: A level editor is typically very specific to the game, so you need to elaborate some more on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Nitro Level Editor - it's XML based and fit for virtually any 2D game or application. http://code.google.com/p/nle/